# Dynamically Change Collapsing Toolbar Title

Tags: android, android-layout

In the default layout provided in android studio with a collapsing toolbar, I've added a floating action button. Within the Scrolling Activity's `onCreate()` method, I wrote this -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ScrollingActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New Title");
        }
    });
}
```

Please tell me why the title won't change and how to change the title whenever fab is pressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change collapsing toolbar title use :

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("yourTitle");
```

Comment: does not works within the onClick method of fab button

Comment: Need to pass `this` object from ScrollingActivity to fab's onClick method. But how?

Comment: create a collapsingToolbarLayout instance before your onCreate methode